# prime number takes 0 arguments issue

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error of "No overload for method 'IsPrime' takes 0 arguments when I call IsPrime in the event handler?

```
public bool IsPrime(int testNum)
{
    // return True if argument is prime number
    // return false otherwise

    // A prime number is a natural number that has exactly two divisors, 1 and the number its self.
    // 

    if (testNum == 1) return false; // by definition of Prime numbers, 1 is not a prime
    if (testNum == 2) return true; // short circuit out, we know that 2 is the first prime number

    for (int i = 2; i < testNum; ++i)  {
       if (testNum % i == 0)  return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: where are you calling it?

Comment: That happens because the caller doesn't pass any arguments (that's what errors states - just try to read it once again, now carefully)

Comment: How are you invoking the method?

Comment: You're probably going to need to show the caller

Comment: You have to pass an argument to the method when you're calling it. Your 'IsPrime` method specifies one parameter so the invocation would be `IsPrime(9)`, for example.

Comment: I got it, apologies, I was calling with an empty set so no values were being sent to the boolean. Idiotic question. Thank you.

Comment: Just a side note, it would be best if you replaced `testNum` with a variable which contains the square root of it(and cast it to an `int`) just to avoid redundancies.

Answer (score 4):

Your method takes one argument `testNum`. If you don't pass it while calling this method. The compile time error occurs saying:

```
No overload for method 'IsPrime' takes 0 arguments
```

Wrong call:

```
IsPrime();  //no argument is being passed
```

Right way to invoke this:

```
IsPrime(3);  //any integer can be passed
```

Comment: This cleared it up for me, thank you.